# .htaccess redirect with space %20 not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a link like this:

```
http://www.expamle.com/folder1/folder2/folder%20/file.html
```

I want to 301 redirect it with .htaccess to:

```
http://www.expamle.com/folder1/folder2/folder/file.html
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/folder1\/folder2\/folder\%20\/file\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder/file.html [R=301,L]
```

but I'm getting:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /folder1/folder2/folder /file.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I also tried this

```
Redirect 301 /folder1/folder2/folder%20/Export1.htm http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder/file.html
```

but got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add quotes like this:

```
Redirect 301 "/folder1/folder2/folder /Export1.htm" http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder/file.html
```